# Capturing mouseEevents on a container, bypassing its children

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am building an RIA application using Flex 4.6 that contains a main borderContainer (page) that can contain some other borderContainers (graphic or text elements).

I added an event listener on the page to listen to click events:

```
page.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, true);
```

clickHandler looks like this:

```
private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Remove event listeners
    page.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, true);

    // Get click position
    objX = event.localX;
    objY = event.localY;
}
```

My problem is that although the event's currentTarget is always the page (normal), the target can either be the page or one of its children, and then localX doesn't give me the position on the page but on the child.

Is there a way to make sure the page is always the target of the event? Something like stopping the capturing phase on the page so it doesn't go deeper?

Thanks in advance for your help

Darrel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be asking the wrong question. As I understand it, you want the x/y position relative to 'page'. You can use the [DisplayObject#globalToLocal()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal%28%29) function to find this.

Just take the the global coordinates and convert them to local coordinates relative to 'page':

```
var coordinates:Point = new Point(event.stageX, event.stageY);
coordinates = page.globalToLocal(coordinates);
objX = coordinates.x;
objY = coordinates.y;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you put me on the right track.
I think you meant:

    `var coordinates:Point = page.globalToLocal(new Point(event.stageX, event.stageY));`

If you can edit your answer, i will accept it.

Comment: @dferer As far as I'm concerned they would both yield the same result. I don't know your concrete situation of course. I'll update my answer in a generic way.

Comment: Your code asks the page to convert "local" coordinates to stage coordinates without knowing if they are really local, as they could be relative to one of the page's children. I think this is a mistake. As you mentioned, my need is to get the coordinates relative to the page. The correction i suggested is to ask the page to convert stage coordinates to local ones, which does not give the same result.

Comment: @dferer I see your point now. I didn't have this issue in my little test setup of course. Editing again ;)